# Process started from init.d takes a long time

Tags: linux, init.d

I have a wget https://url request that i want to launch from a daemon started from /etc/init.d

If launched from /etc/init.d, it will take approximately 10 times longer than if i launch it from a console.

I checked with time(1) and the difference is only in real: not in user or sys
I tried to renice the process, but this does not change anything. 
I checked ulimit settings, and they are identical

Are there any process limits active during startup, that differ from those of interactive login sessions?

Anyone seen something similar? Could it have anything to do with PREEMPTION?

Comment: is it started before networking comes up?

Comment: no, wget is not called immediately during startup, but later, when the daemon reads a value from the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that this strange behaviour is gone if i remove the -U option from wget. 
No idea what made wget behave so strange.